# Correct wait to wait for an element to disappear?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Correct wait to wait for an element to disappear?

I have an ajax loader which loads after for example clicking on a button, is my method correct inorder to wait for a particular load bar which takes the full width and height of a screen to disappear?

```
    public void waitUntilAjaxLoaderDisapears() {
    // Wait up to 2minutes for the element to disappear
    WebDriverWait ajaxWait = new WebDriverWait(this.driver, 60);
    ajaxWait.pollingEvery(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    try {
        //tempWait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".modal-body")));
        ajaxWait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'ajax_loader')]")));
    } catch (UnhandledAlertException e) {
         Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
         alert.accept();
    }catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
        //
    }catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
        // do nothing
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        // do nothing
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: "screen to disappear" are we able to create a webelement for this disappearing screen?

Comment: @santhosh kumar when the loader screen appear i can confirm the locator is as listed above

Comment: one observation is polling time should be less than the actual wait time. It has to be less than 60

Comment: @santhosh kumar that is exactly the problem, thanks so much! looks like im lacking on some good old coffee on this fine friday morning

Comment: I have posted this as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i got the issue. The polling time should be less than the overall wait time. So it can be,

```
 WebDriverWait ajaxWait = new WebDriverWait(this.driver, 60);
 ajaxWait.pollingEvery(**5**, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Instead of

```
WebDriverWait ajaxWait = new WebDriverWait(this.driver, 60);
ajaxWait.pollingEvery(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Hope this helps you. Thanks.